# Error in Run Apple Script custom application -10661

Tags: applescript

I am trying to run an application using apple script but it throws an error. The command which I try to run is:

```
tell application "MyApplication" to launch
```

An error I received:

```
error "An error of type -10661 has occurred." number -10661
```

I am trying to run this command in apple script editor. And my application exists in the Application folder. When I directly run this application it's working. When I try to run other default applications its working fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure "MyApplication" is scriptable? If so, are you sure there is a "launch" command? Double check the dictionary for the application.

As an alternative, you can tell the Finder to open the application

```
Tell application "Finder" to open file "path:to:your:application.app"
```

Comment: `activate` and `launch` are a little (but actually substantially) different. And it is probably true that the vast majority of applications will be "activate-able" (even if they're not scriptable) whereas the `launch` command will not be recognized.